# TCL is reading the pound character incorrect

Tags: string, tcl

I am reading a file.  If the first character of the line is `#` I want to skip the line.  However tcl is converting `#` to `{`. How do I overcome and why is that happening?

```
test.txt
# Skip this line
George Washington
end of test.txt

set fileResults [readFile c:/tclPrograms/test.txt]
foreach item $fileResults {
    set row [split $item ","]
    puts [string range $row 0 0]
    puts [string index $row 0]
}
```

Both are printing `{` and not `#` If I switch the first character to `/` it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line

```
set row [split $item ","]
```

sets `row` to a list, but then the next two lines

```
puts [string range $row 0 0]
puts [string index $row 0]
```

use string operations on that list, which makes no sense.
Since you want to skip the whole line if it starts with `#` you should get the first character *before* you split it up as a list, i.e.

```
puts [string range $item 0 0]
```

and probably

```
if {[string range $item 0 0] eq "#"} continue
```

or even

```
if {[string index $item 0] eq "#"} continue
```

By the way, I'm assuming that the `readFile` you use here returns a list of the file lines, it's not a standard Tcl command.

Comment: thanks.  I needed to change my `readFile` function.  I was returning a string and not a list of values.

Comment: I usually recommend `string match "#*" $item` for this sort of check (after trimming).